Is there a function in Haskell that changes ord of a Char again into the same Char?
Is there a function in Haskell that changes ord of a Char again into the same Char?
For expample:
ord 'a' ----> 'a'

chr, or toEnum. Please do a bare amount of research before asking a question here. You can use Hoogle to locate a function with a given type.

I'm not sure I understand the question, but...
> id 'a'
'a'

